# Problems with Calc's DATEVALUE()

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I am baffled by the behaviour of LibreOffice Calc's *DATEVALUE()* function, as per the following example:

```
Cell          content               format       display

 A1       01/07/2017                Date        01/07/2017
 B1       =DATEVALUE("01/07/2017")  Quantity         42917
 C1       =DATEVALUE(A1)            (whatever)     Err:502
 D1       =DATEVALUE(TEXT(A1;"DD/MM/YYYY";@))
                                    (whatever)      #NAME?
```

Why C1 and D1 do not display the correct answer, which is B1? It will be surely very evident, but I do not see it. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

As documented: [DATEVALUE](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/DATEVALUE) "Text is a valid date expression and must be entered with quotation marks." In other words: The argument **Text** must be a string and not a date value. But your `A1`value is a date value already. If you wants to see the number, simply format `A1` as `Number` or use the formula `=A1` in another cell and format this cell as `Number`.

And `TEXT(A1;"DD/MM/YYYY";@)` is simply wrong syntax and the `#NAME?` error comes from the third argument `@` which is not supported. See [TEXT](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Text_Functions#TEXT) -> only two arguments.

If you have a date value within a formula, then the result cell will possibly be automatically formatted as  date also. If you don't need this, for example because the need is calculating day differences, then reformat it as `Number`.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for the mistakes in my previous message and you are surely right in your criticisms, Axel. Thanks very much.

But unfortunately I have not been able to solve my initial problem just with the correct syntax. It originated when trying to evaluate the formulas in one cell such as *B1*:

```
Cell       content                          display
 A1     01/07/2017                         01/07/2017
 B1     =DATEVALUE($A$1) - DATE(2000;1;1)  Err:502
```

As *A1* is an input cell for dates (in an astronomical spreadsheet) I did not understand in the beginning the reason for aplying to it the *datevalue()* function, which seemed redundant, but I tried in any case to make it work, as the apparently most direct solution (given that the goal was just to perform an arithmetical operation with dates)

```
 C1     =$A$1 - DATE(2000;1;1)              #VALUE
```

did not work in the document (which was imported from an *Excel* original).  In my tests *C1* does not display an error but a date as a result, only that it is an incorrect one.

What I take for a correct *rendition* of the original formula

```
 D1    =DATEVALUE(CONCATENATE(CHAR(34);$A$1;CHAR(34)))-DATE(2000;1;1)
                                            Err:502
```

has not worked neither has:

```
 E1    =DATEVALUE(CONCATENATE(CHAR(34);TEXT($A$1;"DD/MM/YYYY");CHAR(34)))-DATE(2000;1;1)
                                            Err:502
```

The solution that I have finally found is:

```
 F1    =N($A$1) - DATE(2000;1;1)            6391
```

which gives the correct answer and is simple. So the problem seems at least practically solved, althoug I remain quite baffled about how date operations have to be rightly managed in Calc.

Regards